# Excel 2007 - refering value from other worksheet in another function in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have two worksheets. I have data in Sheet2 in column A for which i want to use average function. In sheet1 i have values in only two cells. B1 cell has value 5 and B2 cell has value 15. Using these two parameters, i want to average the data in Sheet2 for column A from A5 to A15. If i change the parameters in Sheet1, automatically the average calculations in Sheet2 should change

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You need to better explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: may i was not able to explain it in first attempt..... but later i clarified what is expected and got the solution. Thanks

Comment: Glad you got the answer you needed. This is a community, so you should still clarify your question for the sake of others who may search the site with the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDIRECT`.

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A"&Sheet1!B1&":A"&Sheet1!B2))
```

In evaluating, you get:

- After first substitution by excel, this becomes:

  ```
  =AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A"&5&":A"&15))
  ```
- Concatenate...

  ```
  =AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A5:A15"))
  ```
- Evaluation and result:

  ```
  =AVERAGE(A5:A15)
  ```

Comment: =AVERAGE(INDIRECT("A"&Sheet1!B1&":A"&Sheet1!B2))

Comment: Excellent ..... just one & sign was missing....... Thanks a lot

Comment: @user283173 You're welcome. I missed it when typing the formula like that but noticed a little while ago. The edit should have caught it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply use formula `=AVERGAGE(Sheet1!A5:A15)` in Sheet2!

When building the formula, you can navigate to other sheets and select the ranges directly with the mouse.

Comment: I want to use 5 and 15 from Sheet1, Where as average should be of Column A in Sheet 2

Comment: sorry, mixed up sheet1 and 2 - see my update

Comment: Sir my data is in Sheet2. What you have mentioned  will average the data from Sheet1, but i dont have any data in sheet1......  In Sheet1, I have only two cells B1 ( having value 5 ) and cell B2 having value is 15. Using these two parameters, i want to average the data in sheet2 from A5 to A15. Hope you got my question

Comment: ah, now i see. use Jerry's answer then!